# VirtualBox Guest Additions: clipboard doesn't work

Tags: debian, virtualbox, clipboard

I'm having a problem concerning the shared clipboard between a Debian 10 Guest and a Windows 10 Host.
So far, I have done the following:

`sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

insert guest additions
go into the folder containing the Guest Additions files and:

`sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

`sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf 'raphael'`

This seems to work correctly because the screen effectively gets larger and fits the size of the window, however even after enabling the bidirectionnal clipboard in the settings, it doesn't seem to apply these settings and the clipboard isn't shared in any direction.

Any advices on this?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a known issue - https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19336

Fix appears to be to either downgrade to v6.1.2 or use a 'Test' Guest Additions build (currently [6.1.5](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.5-136459.iso)) worked for me although I'm not sure Display Auto-sizing is working correctly.

Comment: downgrading to Guest Additions 6.1.2 solved it indeed. Thank you!